# How to separate template and style for mobile and desktop in component Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, responsive-design, frontend

Template for mobile and desktop are very different, but have one logic in component. I need separate template and design for mobile and desktop in separate files. I want include template and design depending on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf`

```
template: `
<div *ngIf="isMobile">
  mobile content
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isMobile">
  desktop content
</div>
```

The Angular2 team had an attempt to support this directly using the `@View()` decorator but removed it a few versions ago because it didn't seem to be a good strategy. Currently there is no built-in support for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I will use this method I will have a lot of many code. Are there other ways?

Comment: Maybe I will check resolution of device in first component and user will redirect on another component

Comment: Build tools seem to allow to do that but I'm not usind TS and don't know details. I guess you would need to build 2 different applications.

Comment: I've created 2 different applications. I made common code like npm package and connect to each project. All work like need!